# How to read this or what type of encode is used to create this message?

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

I receive message from the server and it looks as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<meta>
    <code>0</code>
    <message>ÐÑÐ¸Ð±ÐºÐ° Ð¾Ð±ÑÐ°Ð±Ð¾ÑÐºÐ¸ Ð·Ð°Ð¿ÑÐ¾ÑÐ°</message>
</meta>
```

It is not UTF, right? How I can read this in java?

Comment: It looks perfectly valid UTF-8 to me... Only the message contents don't really make any sense at all. Tried anything yet?

Comment: @fge: the `<Message>` DOES NOT contain a valid UTF-8 sequence, actually. This is likely the case where the data is getting encoded multiple times when it should not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually looks valid, [according to Google](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%C3%90%C3%91%C3%90%C2%B8%C3%90%C2%B1%C3%90%C2%BA%C3%90%C2%B0%20%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%90%C2%B1%C3%91%C3%90%C2%B0%C3%90%C2%B1%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%91%C3%90%C2%BA%C3%90%C2%B8%20%C3%90%C2%B7%C3%90%C2%B0%C3%90%C2%BF%C3%91%C3%90&hl=en&tbo=d&ei=7b3iUMTuIIHq8gTpiYG4Cw&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU&fp=a256d4f28226d313&bpcl=40096503&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=667).

Joking. :)

Also, the website at 2cyr.com (http://2cyr.com/decode/) gave a few leads, and it looks it could be some Central European Encoding (ISO8859-2 in particular)

Your best bet is to rely in tools like Mozillas' Chardet and work this string in particular - in plain Java pseudocode:

```
new String(oldString.getBytes("ISO8859-2"), "UTF-8")
```

But it looks like spam after all. Or perhaps an Alternate Reality Game in Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Remember to word the answer such that it makes sense even if the link goes dead. "This tool" is not very descriptive as to what a potential future bycomer is supposed to look for should the link be dead.

Comment: Jan, thanks for spotting writing biases. I haven't thought about it, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Message>` tag DOES NOT contain valid UTF-8.  Its contents consist of the following byte sequence:

**D0 D1** D0 B8 D0 B1 D0 BA D0 B0 20 D0 BE D0 B1 **D1** D0 B0 D0 B1 D0 BE **D1** D0 BA D0 B8 20 D0 B7 D0 B0 D0 BF **D1** D0 BE **D1** D0 B0

The highlighted bytes are not valid UTF-8.